# Помогите разобраться с обратной формой

Tags: javascript

Что написано не правильно? внизу указал на что жалуется

```
  <h4>Заказать звонок</h4>
</div>
<div class="ajax_form" id="clback">
  <div class="field">
    <input id='name_name' type="text" name="name" required="">
    <label  for="phone_phone">Ваше имя</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="tel" id="phone_phone" name="phone" required="">
    <label  for="phone_phone">Телефон</label>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="phone()" id='phone-button' class="submit ">Заказать обратный звонок</button>

<input type="hidden" name="af_action" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#phone-button").click(function() {
    phone = document.getElementById('phone_phone').value
    name = document.getElementById('name_name').value
    document.getElementById('phone-button').innerHTML = 'Отправляется...'
    $.get("https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/", {name:name, phone:phone})
      .done(function (data) {
        document.location.href = "https://taxigreenline.ru/yes/";
```

после чего получаю вот такие ошибки

> Uncaught TypeError: phone is not a function
>   at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1345)
>   onclick @ (index):1345
>   jquery.min.js:2 GET https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/?name=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80&phone=89787635718 net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: www.taxigreenline.ru вот ссылка на сайт. Сверху кнопка Вам перезвонить ? проверьте работоспособность и посмотрите ошибки .Код я скинул,помогите разобраться пожалуйста ю

Answer (score 2):

Я уже говорил Вам:

уберите `onclick="phone()"` из

```
<button onclick="phone()" id='phone-button' class="submit ">
```

В Вашем коде нет функции `phone`.

Comment: Когда я убираю onclick ,при нажатии на кнопку вообще ничего не происходит

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 GET https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/?name=u0992456&phone=89787635718 net::ERR_FAILED и что с этой ошибкой делать ?!

Comment: Не может быть. У Вас перегружается страница. Поэтому Вам кажется, что "ничего не происходит". Добавьте в кнопку `type="button"`.

Comment: Игорь я новичек. Могли бы вы мне помочь написать правильно все ?с учетом type=button куда его добавить ?

Comment: `<button type="button" ...`

Comment: его можно вместо onclick поставить ?

Comment: Никаких "вместо". Откуда этот `onclick` вообще взялся?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="submit ">Заказать звонок</button> у меня сейчас такой код. Я не понимаю куда добавить type=button

Comment: Вместо `type="submit"` напишите `type="button"`.

Comment: Вы могли бы перейти по www.taxigreenline.ru  и посмотреть работоспособность кнопки Вам перезвонить ?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED Жалуется на страницу благодарности